# If a protected question takes 10 rep, why isn't 101 enough?

Tags: support

I was tempted to add to [An adjective to describe a pregnant woman's swollen belly?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44420/an-adjective-to-describe-a-pregnant-womans-swollen-belly), but there's no answer button, and the explanation is a minimum rep of 10, and I've got (thanks to association) 101.
?

Comment: It seems like it is because the "on this site" part. According to the description, "To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site." To get 10 rep points on this site, you can try answering a question on the main site to get it upvoted. By the way, welcome to ELL!

Comment: @DamkerngT. - Yes, that's it. The 101 assumes you know SE protocol on comments and such, but it doesn't work for protected questions.

Answer (score 2):

[Because the association bonus doesn't count towards answering protected questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/191706). The bonus is granted to give you some basic privileges because you've proven you understand how the Stack Exchange software works in general. The purpose of protecting a question is to prevent poor answers from users who haven't proven they know how to make quality contributions to a site. The former does not imply the latter; just because you have a bunch of rep on Stackoverflow (and thus know how to code) doesn't mean you're knowledgeable about English, gardening, bicycles, travel, etc.